# XMLBeans - Handle the namespace

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd, xmlbeans

I complete the xmlbean tutorial with XML file and XSD file and successfully access all data.

Now i add the namespace for XML and XSD file recompile and recreate the jar file. After this the package name change in the java file but here i am facing issue as i am getting the null for each xsd parameter.Following is XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="serverDetail">
<xsd:element name="ServerConfig">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="driverClassName" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Following is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Contains server details-->
<ServerConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="serverDetail" xsi:SchemaLocation="serverConfig.xsd">
       <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
       <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
       <user>root</user>
       <password>root</password>
</ServerConfig>
```

Following is java class files

```
     import serverDetail.ServerConfigDocument;
     import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

     String filePath = "E:/Gradle/DemoTest/src/serverConfig.xml";
     java.io.File inputXMLFile = new java.io.File(filePath);
     try {
        ServerConfigDocument serverDoc= ServerConfigDocument.Factory.parse(inputXMLFile);
        ServerConfigDocument.ServerConfig serverConfig=serverDoc.getServerConfig();
        System.out.println("Server details\nDriverClassName " + serverConfig.getDriverClassName());
        System.out.println("Url is " + serverConfig.getUrl());
        System.out.println("User is " + serverConfig.getUser());
        System.out.println("Password is " + serverConfig.getPassword());
    } catch (XmlException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So here i am getting the output as null.

```
 Server details
 DriverClassName null
 Url is null
 User is null
 Password is null
```

Can anyone help me here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the `xsd:schema` element.

As currently written, your schema declares a top-level `ServerConfig` element in the schema's `targetNamespace`, but "local" element declarations inside the `complexType` do not take on the `targetNamespace`, so XMLBeans is expecting an XML document that looks like

```
<ns:ServerConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:ns="serverDetail"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="serverDetail serverConfig.xsd">
   <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
   <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
   <user>root</user>
   <password>root</password>
</ns:ServerConfig>
```

You haven't provided any `driverClassName`, `url`, etc. elements without a namespace, so XMLBeans correctly gives null for the corresponding properties.

If you want local elements to be in the `targetNamespace` as well, then you need to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the schema

```
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               targetNamespace="serverDetail"
               elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

with this in place the following would validate successfully

```
<ServerConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="serverDetail"
              xsi:schemaLocation="serverDetail serverConfig.xsd">
   <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
   <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
   <user>root</user>
   <password>root</password>
</ServerConfig>
```

P.S. namespace identifiers should normally be URIs, so instead of `serverDetail` you should use something like `urn:serverDetail` or a fake `http://` URL of some kind.

Comment: Thanks Ian, Its working fine after the changes which you suggested.